# Error: Invalid index file: Anaconda

Tags: anaconda, conda, samtools

I'm trying to install samtools with conda (Ubuntu 16.04):

```
conda install -c bioconda samtools
```

But i get this index error:

```
Error: Invalid index file: conda-forge/linux-64/repodata.json.bz2
```

Somebody knows about this? I have tried unsuccessfully to update it..

Comment: Can you try removing `conda-forge` from your channels? `conda config --remove channels conda-forge`

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't work: Next error: Error: --remove without --force is not implemented yet

Comment: Did you try adding the `--force` option? Also, I don't have that problem when I try to remove a channel...